# How can I composite Landsat-7 RGB tif images to the true color image using python?

Tags: landsat, rgb, landsat-7

I use below codes to composite Landsat-7 Surface Reflectance band(B3, B2, B1) images to the true color image. but the result was a wrong image. How can I solve it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal

# Function to read and normalize image
def read_and_normalize_image(image_path):
    dataset = gdal.Open(image_path)
    array = dataset.ReadAsArray()
    # Normalize pixel values to range [0, 1]
    normalized_array = (array - np.min(array)) / (np.max(array) - np.min(array))
    return normalized_array

# Paths to R, G, B images
b3_path = "/Users/lsj/Downloads/LE07_L2SP_115036_20231011_20231106_02_T1/LE07_L2SP_115036_20231011_20231106_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF"
b2_path = "/Users/lsj/Downloads/LE07_L2SP_115036_20231011_20231106_02_T1/LE07_L2SP_115036_20231011_20231106_02_T1_SR_B2.TIF"
b1_path = "/Users/lsj/Downloads/LE07_L2SP_115036_20231011_20231106_02_T1/LE07_L2SP_115036_20231011_20231106_02_T1_SR_B1.TIF"

# Read and normalize R, G, B images
b3 = read_and_normalize_image(b3_path)
b2 = read_and_normalize_image(b2_path)
b1 = read_and_normalize_image(b1_path)

# Stack R, G, B arrays to create RGB image
rgb_image = np.dstack((b3, b2, b1))

# Increase brightness by adding 0.5 to all pixels
brightened_image = rgb_image + 0.5
brightened_image[brightened_image > 1] = 1  # Ensure values are within [0, 1]

# Display RGB image
plt.imshow(brightened_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Brightened True Color Image')
plt.show()
```

[image: lan]